# Idiomatic way to pass methods as parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, binding

```
// This didn't work because "this" in display_previous_room was Window instead of a Collection object.
this.listener.simple_combo("left",this.collection.display_previous_room);

// This worked
this.listener.simple_combo("right",this.collection.display_next_room.bind(this.collection));
```

Is this the right way to do it in javascript ? Or should I change this.listener.simple_combo (which is a third party library) to allow the caller to add method arguments like this

```
this.listener.simple_combo("right",this.collection.display_next_room,this.collection,{...}); // simple_combo(key,function/method,binding,arguments to the function/method)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the Collection object like this

```
this.listener.simple_combo("right", this.collection.display_next_room.bind(this.collection));
```

so that the `this` will refer the proper collection object.